# Using only the axioms for a field, give a formal proof for $\frac{1}{z_{1}z_{2}}=\frac{1}{z_{1}}\cdot \frac{1}{z_{2}}$.

Tags: complex-numbers, field-theory

> Using only the axioms for a field, give a formal proof for $\frac{1}{z_{1}z_{2}}=\frac{1}{z_{1}}\cdot \frac{1}{z_{2}}$, where $z_{1},z_{2}\in \mathbb{C}$.

This is my attempt:

$\frac{1}{z_{1}z_{2}}=\frac{1}{z_{1}z_{2}}\cdot 1=\frac{1}{z_{1}z_{2}}\cdot z_{1}z_{1}^{-1}=\frac{1}{z_{2}}z_{1}^{-1}\cdot 1=\frac{1}{z_{2}}z_{1}^{-1}\cdot z_{2}z_{2}^{-1}=z_{1}^{-1}z_{2}^{-1}=\frac{1}{z_{1}}\cdot \frac{1}{z_{2}}$

Is this correct though? Any critique is appreciated!

Comment: You are accepting then that $\frac{1}{z}$ is just a different notation for $z^{-1}$?

Comment: Are you sure it isn't $z_1, z_2 \in \Bbb{C} \smallsetminus \{0\}$?

Comment: By what definition of $\frac{1}{z}$ do you prove $\frac{1}{z_1z_2}z_1=\frac{1}{z_2}$?

Comment: $\frac{1}{z_1z_2}\cdot z_1=\frac 1 {z_2}$ is true but it is not an axiom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof assumes that$$\frac1{z_1z_2}\cdot z_1=\frac1{z_2}.$$How do you know that?

I would use the fact that\begin{align}\left(\frac1{z_1}\cdot\frac1{z_2}\right)\cdot(z_1\cdot z_2)&=\left(\frac1{z_1}\cdot\frac1{z_2}\right)\cdot(z_2\cdot z_1)\\&=\left(\left(\frac1{z_1}\cdot\frac1{z_2}\right)\cdot z_2\right)\cdot z_1\\&=\left(\frac1{z_1}\cdot\left(\frac1{z_2}\cdot z_2\right)\right)\cdot z_1\\&=\left(\frac1{z_1}\cdot1\right)\cdot z_1\\&=\frac1{z_1}\cdot z_1\\&=1.\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

The inverse of an element is unique, therefore it suffices to show that
$$\frac{1}{z_1}\cdot\frac{1}{z_2} (z_1 z_2) = 1$$
which is not too hard.

Proof that the inverse is unique:

Suppose $xy=1=xz$, then $y=x^{-1}xy = x^{-1}xz = z$.